# Is there any way to filter a nested lists with a linq query, so that i end up with filtered list of adequatly filtered lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem filtering a Lists of strings being nested in a bigger list.

I tried something like this:

```
myList.FindAll(d => d.activities.Any(i => i.type.Contains("read")));
```

but it seems like any is returning

I have a 'UserData' structure as shown:

```
public class UserData
{
   public int id;
   public List<UserActivity> activities;
}
public class UserActivity
{
   public string activity;
   public string type;
}
```

there are f.ex. two types of activity ("read" and "write")

What I'm trying to do is to filter a given `List<UserData> myList` as shown

```
List<UserData> newList = new List<UserData>();

foreach(UserData d in myList){
    UserData newD = new UserData();
    newD.id = d.id;
    newD.activities= d.activities.FindAll(i =>
i.type.Contains("read"));

    if (newD.activities.Any())
        newList.Add(newD);
}
```

Is there a way to do it somehow neatly with Linq query?

What I'm trying to figure out is a short neat Linq query to filter nested lists as I described... I know it may be a cosmetic matter but it still bothers me a lot.

Comment: What is the problem with the "if" statement you are using? Also, I would consider using Where instead of FindAll as FindAll makes a copy of each item: d.activities.Where(a => z.type.Contains("read")).ToList(); And finally, if you want to fix cosmetic matters, you should start by following c# naming conventions for your class properties! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using:

```
newList = myList.Where(d => d.activities.Any(act => act.type.Contains("read")))
    .Select(d => new UserData { id = d.id, activities = new List<UserActivity>( d.activities.FindAll(act => act.type.Contains("read")) ) })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = (from userData in myList
               let newActivities = userData.activities.Where(i => i.type.Contains("read"))
               where newActivities.Any()
               select new UserData { id = userData.id, activities = newActivities.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            List<UserData> newList = myList.Select(x => new UserData() { id = x.id, activities = x.activities.Where(y => y.type.Contains("read")).ToList() })
                .Where(x => x.activities.Count > 0)
                .ToList();
```